# Replace item if is found in other dictionary in item or in key

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, dictionary-comprehension

I need one inline function for this, With these two dicts

```
mi_data = {'aggrLevel': 'region', 'capType': 'VTTLTEAM', 'date': '2021-03-29', 'Business': 'VTTL'}
map_to_A = {'VANTTL': 'VTTL', 'VTLONLY': 'VTL_NORMAL', 'VTTLTEAM': 'VTL_EXPO', 'VTTLCNSOLO': 'VTTL_CN', 'BTCHEM': 'BTCHEM'}
```

Obtain the next result

```
mi_data =  {'aggrLevel': 'region', 'capType': 'VTL_EXPO', 'date': '2021-03-29', 'Business': 'VTTL'}
```

I successfully made it with a regular function

```
def replace_values( d, d2 ):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, str) and v in d2:
            d[k] = d2[v]
    return d    
replace_values(mi_data, map_to_A)
mi_data
```

And I tried with this inline function but it was not successful

```
mi_data = {map_to_A.get(k, k):v for k, v in mi_data.items()}
mi_data
```

I cannot get the replacement in `capType`, I obtain the same

```
mi_data = {'aggrLevel': 'region', 'capType': 'VTCTEAM', 'date': '2021-03-29', 'Business': 'VTTL'}
```

Take care if you run both methods in the same file and if you run the regular function first, it will change `mi_data` and maybe you could think that the inline function is doing the job.

Comment: The `map_to_A` dictionary is completely different...

Comment: *I sucessfully made it with a regular function* the function you posted doesn't do anything, the `if` condition is always `False`. And what is the point of checking if the value is `str`?

Comment: `map_to_A.get(k, k)` should be `map_to_A.get(v, k)`

Comment: there is no VTCTEAM key in `map_to_A`  so you are getting same k,v in `mi_data`

Answer (score 0):

The following dictionary comprehension works:

```
{k: (map_to_A[v] if v in map_to_A.keys() else v) for k,v in mi_data.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'aggrLevel': 'region', 'capType': 'VTL_EXPO', 'date': '2021-03-29', 'Business': 'VTTL'}
```